# Country selection page implementation

Tags: site-configuration

I want to design a page where a user is taken to once they land on the site for the first time and they can select their country/language there, which gets stored as a cookie. After, the user is redirected back to the site. What are some possible approaches to handling this?

I thought about setting the "country selection" page as the default page in configuration file, and check whether the cookie is there before everything is loaded -> redirect to regular "home" if yes, but this does not cover the case where the user comes from google/gets link from outside (would it maybe make sense to create an item renderer for this?) Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I would approach this:

1. Define a rendering that shows an overlay on any page it's included in.
2. When a user selects a country via this rendering:

   - Send an AJAX request to the server;
   - Take any actions needed based on the user's selection;
   - Add a cookie to the user's browser indicating that a country has been chosen;
   - Hide the overlay.
3. Include this component as a part of every layout. Only render it in case the cookie is not set.

This way, you don't need a separate page and redirection logic. Country selection will be (conditionally) shown on every page.

An additional benefit of this approach is that you can use the same component to allow users to *change* their country, if that ever becomes a requirement.

Comment: thank you! seems really helpful that it can be used to change the country later on